# Web Host / Service to Fetch Batch of URLs

Tags: web-hosting, web-services

I have a list of about one million URLs that I would like fetched and would rather not run this process on my own web server. I am wondering if there are any commercial solutions to this - i.e. any services that will take my list of URLs and return the HTML for each (running it behind proxies, etc., if necessary).

Answer (score 1):

A Linux virtual private server (some priced at less than $10/mo) can be used to complete this task with minimal configuration - see the [wget man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) for instructions if you choose to go this route.